# Python utility to filter records in a dataset into retention1 dataframe and retention2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter on an existing dataframe based on the condition below. Here is the dataset. There are few more conditions added which I am trying to find solution.

[Complete dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AalvA.png)

Conditions:

I need to categorize them into retention1, retention2 or both. Categorize it in retention1 if the values are in retention1 and retention2 records are all None. Similarly for retention2, retention2 column has values and retention1 is having None. But for Mixed retention- for each 'name' record you can have retention1 as None and retention2 as None. but there should be one valid value of column - retention1 or retention2 as shown in the dataset.
While categorizing, compare Cluster ID with AZ_URL. If cluster ID is in second part of AZ_URL then the correct values are the first element of retention1 or retention2.
Compare Cluster ID with AZ_URL. If cluster ID is in first part of AZ_URL then the correct values are second element of retention1 or retention2.

Retention1: The name def, has two records with retention2 having values None and retention1 is [3;4] and [3;1] so check the clusterID in AZ_URL, since it is in the first part of AZ_URL keep the second part of retention 1 in the output record below.

[Retention1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FC1PS.png)

Retention2: For name rls, clusterID bn4323 is in second part of AZ_URL. So extract first part of retention2 - 7 and first part of snapshot retention - Monthly.

[Retention2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8dp1.png)

Mix Retention: Names abc, cgh come in mix retention as they both have two records and record1 has retention1 not None (and retention2 is None) and record2 has retention2 Not None (and retention1 is None)

[Mix retention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bgtv.png)

I tried writing the code below using pandas but I am unable to find the function for this.

Retention1 calculation:

```
m=df['retention1'].notna()
n=df['retention2'].notna() 

df3=df.loc[m & ~n,['Name', 'ClusterID','Az_URL','retention1']].dropna(axis=1)

df3['retention1']=df3['retention1'].str.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False)
```

Retention2 calculation:

```
df=df.replace({'None':None})
m=df['retention1'].notna()
n=df['retention2'].notna() 

df4=df.loc[n & ~m,['Name', 'ClusterID','Az_URL','retention2', 'retention snapshot']].dropna(axis=1)

df4['retention2']=df4['retention2'].str.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False)
df4['retention2']=df4['retention2'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z ]+)',expand=False)
```

Mix retention calculation:

```
df=df.replace({'None':None})
m=df['retention1'].notna()
n=df['retention2'].notna() 

df_merge = df.groupby("name").agg(lambda x['retention1']: list(['retention1']))
```

I need suggestions to improve these new dataframes, lambda as it will help in populating reports in a better way.

Comment: what is the output of `type(df.loc[0,'retention1'])`

Comment: Why use `[5;5]` and not merely `5`?

Comment: @Corralien, this is because the dataset is generated after performing few computations by the other team. The data was even more  complicated earlier (list of lists) having something like this- 
[[1;1];[1;1];[2;2];[1;1]]. Then we simplified it. Hope this helps!

Comment: @AnuragDabas, I have added few more conditions for mix, retention1, retention2 calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try via `loc` and since there are alternate None in 'retension1' and in 'retension2' so a single condition will work:

```
df=df.replace({'None':None})
m=df['retention1'].notna()
#m=(df['retention1'].notna()) & (df['retention2'].isna())
df1=df.loc[m].dropna(axis=1)
df1['retention1']=df1['retention1'].str.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False)
df2=df.loc[~m].dropna(axis=1)
df2['retention2']=df2['retention2'].str.extract(r'(\d+)',expand=False)
```

output of `df1`:

```
  Name Policy retention1
0  abc    123          5
1  cgh    789          1
```

output of `df2`:

```
  Name Policy retention2
0  abc    456          6
1  cgh    675          2
```

Comment: I have added few more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean by:

```
>>> retention1 = df.loc[df['retention1'].notna()].drop('retention2', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> retention1['retention1'] = retention1['retention1'].str.extract('(\d)')
>>> retention1
  Name Policy retention1
0  abc    123          5
1  cgh    789          1
>>> retention2 = df.loc[df['retention2'].notna()].drop('retention1', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> retention2['retention2'] = retention2['retention2'].str.extract('(\d)')
>>> retention2
  Name Policy retention2
0  abc    456          6
1  cgh    675          2
>>>
```